# Why does this inline error function called through macro not return to main?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using a header file to define inline functions for dumping HRESULTS to the immediate window through the use of macros.

From https://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/a_young_person.htm:

```
#define lengthof(rg) (sizeof(rg)/sizeof(*rg))

inline const char* StringFromError(char* szErr, long nSize, long nErr)
{
    _ASSERTE(szErr);
    *szErr = 0;
    DWORD cb = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, nErr, 0, szErr, nSize, 0);
    char szUnk[] = "<unknown>";
    if (!cb && nSize >= lengthof(szUnk)) lstrcpyA(szErr, szUnk);
    return szErr;
}

inline void TraceHR(const char* pszFile, long nLine, HRESULT hr)
{

        char szErr[128];
        char sz[_MAX_PATH + lengthof(szErr) + 64];
        wsprintf(sz, "%s(%d) : error 0x%x: %s\n", pszFile, nLine, hr,
            StringFromError(szErr, lengthof(szErr), hr));
        OutputDebugString(sz);
        return;
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TRACEHR(_hr) TraceHR(__FILE__, __LINE__, _hr)
#else
#define TRACEHR(_hr) _hr
#endif

#define HR(ex) { HRESULT _hr = ex; if(FAILED(_hr)) return TRACEHR(_hr), _hr; }
```

I'm calling the macro from:

```
int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_ACCESSDENIED;

    HR(hr);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I'm finding that HR(hr) never returns to main so std::cin.get() never gets called. Is this expected behavior or am I misinterpreting/incorrectly implementing this functionality?
Is there something about this code that calls a stack unwind instead of allowing an opportunity to handle the HR?

Comment: What do you see that indicates it doesn't return to main?

Comment: The macro `HR` contains a `return` that will exit `main`.

Comment: I would say that it's expected behavior since you do `return` in the macro on error, which leaves `main`.

Comment: @VaughnCato As std::cin.get() should prompt before the console is closed and doesn't I'd say it never reaches it. Additionally I've set a breakpoint that it doesn't reach.

Comment: @dyp & Joachim-Pileborg if I remove the return from that void it still never reaches my .get() statement

Comment: @GamerJ5, Both of them explicitly said macro, not the `TraceHR` function. Look at your source after preprocessing and it should become quite clear.

Comment: @chris Gotcha, if(FAILED(_hr)) TRACEHR(_hr), _hr; thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a macro, it is just a simple textual substitution.  So your main becomes:

```
int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = E_ACCESSDENIED;

    { HRESULT _hr = hr; if(FAILED(_hr)) return TRACEHR(_hr), _hr; };

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Since the braces around a `return` statement do not prevent it from returning, the `return` exits from `main()` and `std::cin.get()` is not called.

Comment: You could use RAII to achieve the "always do something at the return" bit. I.e if std::cin::get was in the dtor of a local class it would still be called.

Comment: Detailed explanation, Thanks!